# not load suggestions correctly in autcomplete field primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a problem using primeng, some features like buttons or components like that are not shown correctly. For example, I have an autocomplete field and it is displayed as:

When I type 'e': (that blue bar is the suggestion)

[image]

After, I pick the "suggestion", it shows this:

[image]

Here the piece of code of the field

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="selectedTags" [suggestions]="filteredTagsMultiple" (completeMethod)="filterTagMultiple($event)" styleClass="wid100"
                    [minLength]="1" placeholder="tags" field="name" [multiple]="true" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                </p-autoComplete>
```

I don't know what happen, in console browser not errors are displayed.

Thanks

UPDATE

```
filterTagMultiple(event) {
    let query = event.query;
    this.tagService.getAllTags().subscribe(tags => {
        this.filteredTagsMultiple = this.filterTag(query, tags);
    });
}

filterTag(query, tags: any[]):any[] {
    let filtered : any[] = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        let tag = tags[i];
        if(tag.nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
            filtered.push(tag);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: Who is styleClass="wid100"

Comment: show your `component` code. What do the items in `filteredTagsMultiple` look like?

Comment: @alehn96 I don't know, I copy the example of the official web page, but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: @Nehal post updated.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks @MinMiguelM, please answer the second part too "What do the items in filteredTagsMultiple look like?" Give an example of the object. Your code is trying to map to a `name` field, so if that's not in the object, nothing will show in dropdown either.

Comment: I'm a fool, I see the error, the field name does not exist in the model that I want to map. I'm new in angular.
Thank you so much @Nehal

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then, you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, it's trying to map with `field="name"`, if that property doesn't exist, you will not see anything in the dropdown, rather try to map with an object property that exists.

If you want to map with the whole object, then you don't need to use `field` at all.